# SQL using id selected by name

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have that query:

```
SELECT *
   FROM menu_menuitem
   JOIN menu_menuitemclosuretable 
   ON ((menu_menuitem.id = menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id 
   AND menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id = 99)
   OR (menu_menuitem.id = menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id 
   AND menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id = 99))
   ORDER BY level ASC;
```

It gives right result. But how to get the same, searching not by id, but by slug

| id | slug |
| --- | --- |
| 99 | slug1 |
| 98 | slug2 |

| id | descendent_id | ancestor_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | 98 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

That doesn't work

```
SELECT menu_menuitem.id as id, 
       menu_menuitem.slug,
       menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id,
       menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id,
       (SELECT menu_menuitem.id WHERE menu_menuitem.slug = "third") as current_id
FROM menu_menuitem
JOIN menu_menuitemclosuretable 
ON ((menu_menuitem.id = menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id 
AND menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id = current_id)
OR (menu_menuitem.id = menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id 
AND menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id = current_id))
ORDER BY level ASC;
```

it gives only one record

The tables are:

Table menu_menuitem:

```
CREATE TABLE "menu_menuitem" (
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
INSERT INTO menu_menuitem (id, name)
VALUES( 97, "first");

INSERT INTO menu_menuitem (id, name)
VALUES( 98, "second");

INSERT INTO menu_menuitem (id, name)
VALUES( 99, "third");

INSERT INTO menu_menuitem (id, name)
VALUES( 100,    "IV");

INSERT INTO menu_menuitem (id, name)
VALUES( 101,    "V");
```

Table menu_menuitemclosuretable:

```
CREATE TABLE "menu_menuitemclosuretable" (
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "ancestor_id" bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES "menu_menuitem" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  "descendent_id" bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES "menu_menuitem" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
  )

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (119, 97, 101)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (118, 98, 101)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (117, 99, 101)



INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (116, 101, 101)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (115, 97, 100)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (114, 98, 100)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (113, 99, 100)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (112, 100, 100)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (111, 97, 99)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (110, 98, 99)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (109, 99, 99)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (108, 97, 98)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (107, 98, 98)

INSERT INTO menu_menuitemclosuretable (id, ancestor_id, descendent_id)
VALUES (106, 97, 97)
```

Two tables.one table contains FK to another.

This works, but is it possible to avoid nested query?

```
SELECT menu_menuitem.id as id, 
       menu_menuitem.name,
       menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id,
       menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id,
      (SELECT menu_menuitem.id FROM menu_menuitem WHERE menu_menuitem.slug = "third") as current_id
FROM menu_menuitem


JOIN menu_menuitemclosuretable ON ((menu_menuitem.id = menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id and 
                                    menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id = current_id)
                                OR (menu_menuitem.id = menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id and
                                    menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id = current_id))


ORDER BY level ASC
```

Comment: can you please provide a https://dbfiddle.uk/vRbqFpk_ so that we can check for our self

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: use the link provided add your create tables and add data, then add the queries that produce your problem

Comment: I don't understand how works that site, but that is my tables:

Comment: i have started here https://dbfiddle.uk/ZViVku3k add column names and type to the create table after that writean INSERT INTO with data

Comment: It doesn't work on my computer, I don't know why. But I added create table and insertn code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a column from the `SELECT in a FROM clause, you need to join it first in the` FROM` clause so that it can be used

```
SELECT menu_menuitem.id as id, 
       menu_menuitem.name,
       menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id,
       menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id,
       current_id
FROM menu_menuitem
JOIN menu_menuitemclosuretable 
ON ((menu_menuitem.id = menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id 
AND menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id = current_id)
OR (menu_menuitem.id = menu_menuitemclosuretable.descendent_id 
AND menu_menuitemclosuretable.ancestor_id = current_id))
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT menu_menuitem.id as current_id FROM menu_menuitem WHERE menu_menuitem.name = 'third') t1
--ORDER BY level ASC;
```

| id | name | ancestor_id | descendent_id | current_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | third | 99 | 99 | 99 |
| 98 | second | 98 | 99 | 99 |
| 97 | first | 97 | 99 | 99 |
| 100 | IV | 99 | 100 | 99 |
| 101 | V | 99 | 101 | 99 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j5uXrbEB)